# Can't align items in AppBar

Tags: material-ui

I'm having a hard time aligning some elements in my `AppBar`. I need to place that `MoreVertIcon` to the right, after all elements but it always shows before the children:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
export default class MainMenu extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <AppBar title="Dashboard" iconElementRight={
                <IconMenu
                    iconButtonElement={
                        <IconButton><MoreVertIcon /></IconButton>
                    }
                    targetOrigin={{horizontal: 'right', vertical: 'top'}}
                    anchorOrigin={{horizontal: 'right', vertical: 'top'}}
                >
                    <MenuItem primaryText="Refresh" />
                    <MenuItem primaryText="Help" />
                    <MenuItem primaryText="Sign out" />
                </IconMenu>
            }>
                <FlatButton label="Foo" style={styles.items}/>
                <FlatButton label="Bar" style={styles.items}/>
            </AppBar>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just made a component for all of the right hand stuff like this:

```
var RightSideStuff = React.createClass({
   render() {
    return (
        <span>
            <FlatButton label="Foo" style={styles.items}/>
            <FlatButton label="Bar" style={styles.items}/>

             <IconMenu
                iconButtonElement={
                    <IconButton><MoreVertIcon /></IconButton>
                }
                targetOrigin={{horizontal: 'right', vertical: 'top'}}
                anchorOrigin={{horizontal: 'right', vertical: 'top'}}
            >
                <MenuItem primaryText="Refresh" />
                <MenuItem primaryText="Help" />
                <MenuItem primaryText="Sign out" />
            </IconMenu>
        </span>
    );

}
```

});

Then include it into the original component:

```
  <AppBar title="Dashboard"
          iconElementRight={<RightSideStuff/>}
          style={styles.appbar}
  />
```

This lets the appubar display all that stuff as a group instead of the browser taking control and rendering things in order.